# SAS: Avoid writing a file at every datastep on HD

Tags: performance, sas

Is it possible to avoid writing a file at every datastep in SAS? 
For instance, I start with two SAS data sets called `have1` and `have2` on my HD. I then do these simple SAS data steps:

```
data have3;
merge have1 have2; by id;run;

data have3; set have3;
if id='5' then delete;run;

proc sort data=have3; by id;run;

proc summary data=have3;
by id;
output out=have4
sum(expense)=expense;
run;
```

Can I do the first 2 data steps and the `proc sort` in memory and then write on the HD have4? [In fact I merge using hash objects].

`have3` is a big data set so if I can avoid writing the data on my HD at every data steps that would great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broad answer to your question is that yes, you can avoid some steps; you can use a `view` to avoid writing out datasets, in some cases.  You also could use a memory library (`ramlib`) to define a library in memory rather than on a hard disk.

In your specific case, it seems like some of the processing is unnecessary, in any event.

```
data have3;
merge have1 have2; by id;run;

data have3; set have3;
if id='5' then delete;run;

proc sort data=have3; by id;run;

proc summary data=have3;
by id;
output out=have4
sum(expense)=expense;
run;
```

could be

```
data have3;
merge have1 have2;
by id;
if id='5' then delete;
run;

proc summary data=have3;
class id;
output out=have4 sum(expense)=expense;
run;
```

`Class` doesn't require sorting, and works effectively like `by` in this case.  There's no reason to separate the merge and the delete (even more efficient might be to use `where` statements on the incoming datasets).

You could even define `have3` as a view, if you wanted.

```
data have3 /view=have3;  *other code is the same;
```

You can't have a preexisting dataset named `have3` as well in this case or it will fail.

Comment: Good suggestion with the class statement.  Also worth noting (as the OP mentioned it is a big dataset) it may be worthwhile using the `/ groupinternal` option on the class statement as this can speed it up significantly (as long as the class vars aren't being grouped on formatted values).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.  Unfortunately I usually do group on formatted values, but i'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: `class` really did help! it cut the processing time by half!

Comment: With the class and view option I killed the processing time by 80%..that's significant. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Glad I could finally return the favour and teach you something new for a change ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is another more primitive, but simple, way to clean up the various data sets your program produces. Proc datasets will not prevent files from being created, but you can use it to delete any data that has outlived its usefullness. This example will delete have1 and have2.

```
proc datasets;
 delete have1 have2;
run;
```